# Django redirect to previous page saving queries

Tags: python, sql, django, database

So I have a page that displays a table and on each row I have a button called delete that deletes that row and all the information related to it in my database.

The delete button works fine, as in it deletes the information in my DB, but I'd like to redirect it to the page where I display the table.

The problem is that, to access the page that shows the table, it is done through a search with POST method. I thought of saving the parameters that I save when I do the search in a global variable and then render the table page again, with those saved parameters from the initial search, it kinda works, but not they way I want it: It changes my URL to the one that redirects after clicking delete, and, it doesnt update the page manually, so I still see the row I deleted, tho If i refresh it manually, I can't see the deleted row anymore.

**views.py:**

```
def character_delete (request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        Id = request.GET.get("idChar")
        char = Characterweapons.objects.all().filter(characterid=Id).delete()
        char2 = Characters.objects.all().filter(characterid=Id).delete()

    global cont

    return render(request, 'users/characters_found_table.html',cont)
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Why would you display the table with a POST request? Can you use a standard GET instead? That would make it a lot easier.

Comment: Yea, i can do that! I was just doing it to have a cleaner url

Comment: Unrelated: `xxx.objects.all().filter(...)` can be shortened to `xxx.objects.filter(...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use a GET request instead to display your table. The delete should happen through a POST and use `redirect` (instead of `render`) to go to the GET request again.

If you want to store filter parameters between requests, I suggest you use [Django `Session`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/sessions/) to store that info.

Maybe like this:

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^characters$',
    views.show_characters,
    name='show-characters'),
url(r'^characters/(?P<char_pk>[0-9]+)/delete/$',
    views.delete_character,
    name='delete-character'),
```

**views.py**

```
def show_characters(request):
    # this will be a standard GET request to display the table

    filter_param_1 = request.GET.get('filter_param_1', None)
    if filter_param_1 is None:
        # if there is no GET param, look in the session
        filter_param_1 = request.session.get('filter_param_1', None)
    else:
        # if there is a GET param, store it in the session for the next time
        request.session['filter_param_1'] = filter_param_1

    ctx = {
        'data': Characters.objects.filter(some_field=filter_param_1),
    }
    return render(request, 'users/characters_found_table.html', ctx)

def delete_character(request, char_pk):
    if request.method == "POST":
        character = get_obect_or_404(Characters, pk=char_pk)
        # here you can delete other related objects, if they're not set up for delete CASCADE
        character.delete()
        messages.success(request, 'delete was successful')

    return redirect('show-characters')
```

Does that work for you?

Comment: I can't redirect to 'show-characters' because to load initially, needs the search parameter :(

Comment: @ArnauEspin You can store the search parameters in the session. I edited my answer to include a way to do that. Does that work?

Comment: Also, messages.success doesnt work, I guess I need to import it?

Comment: You can use [`from django.contrib import messages`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/messages/)

Answer (score 1):

Any state changing operation (like delete) should happen as a POST, while any read operation should happen as a GET. In addition you need to do a redirect after any successful POST so the post insn't executed again if the user pushes the back button.

So something like:

urls.py

```
...
(r'^characters/delete/$', views.delete_character),
(r'^characters/$', views.list_characters),
```

and views.py

```
def list_characters(request):
    query_params = request.GET.get('q', '')
    ctx = template.Context({
        ...,
        query_params=urllib.quote(query_params)  # <=== pass the query params to the template
    })
    return render(request, 'users/characters_found_table.html', ctx)
```

in the template, generate delete links like so:

```
<form action="delete/" method=POST>
    <input type=hidden name=q value="{{ query_params }}">
    <input type=hidden name=idChar value="{{ ... }}">
    <button type=submit>delete</button>
</form>
```

then the delete view can be written as

```
def delete_character(request):
    chracter_id = request.POST['idChar']  # fail hard if not provided
    q = request.POST['q']
    Characterweapons.objects.filter(characterid=chracter_id ).delete()
    Characters.objects.filter(characterid=chracter_id ).delete()        
    return http.HttpResponseRedirect('../?q=' + q)  # return to the list url (with search params)
```

This way you don't need to save any global state.